# Decide exact position of figures and plot in knitr R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I had trouble position exactly my plots and figures when knitting to pdf a R Markdown document with knitr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question helped me: https://community.rstudio.com/t/cant-control-position-of-tables-and-figures-in-knitted-pdf-document/37364 , where the answerer uses a text file to fit in the latex instructions for the knit.